# AutoMapper requiring mapping members and constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I am brand new to AutoMapper and am just trying to get my head around the best way to do things.

I quickly ran into a hairy issue mapping between two simple, but realistic, object models. The first is for a service layer:

```
public sealed class GeoLocation
{
    public GeoLocation(
        double latitude,
        double longitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double Latitude { get; private set; }

    public double Longitude { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class Location
{
    public Location(
        string name,
        GeoLocation geoLocation)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.GeoLocation = geoLocation;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public GeoLocation GeoLocation { get; private set; }
}
```

And the second is a simplified representation of the above for a database layer:

```
public sealed class LocationEntity
{
    public LocationEntity(
        string name,
        double latitude,
        double longitude)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public double Latitude { get; }

    public double Longitude { get; }
}
```

If I attempt to map the types with a simple `CreateMap<Location, LocationEntity>().ReverseMap()` call, I predictably get a problem when validating the mappings:

```
AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
===============================================
Location -> LocationEntity (Destination member list)
UserQuery+Location -> UserQuery+LocationEntity (Destination member list)

No available constructor.
===============================================
LocationEntity -> Location (Destination member list)
UserQuery+LocationEntity -> UserQuery+Location (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
GeoLocation
No available constructor.
```

Fair enough. I didn't feel like mapping every constructor parameter, so I tried calling `ConstructUsing`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(
    config =>
    {
        config
            .CreateMap<Location, LocationEntity>()
            .ConstructUsing((source, _) => new LocationEntity(source.Name, source.GeoLocation?.Latitude ?? 0.0, source.GeoLocation?.Longitude ?? 0));
        config
            .CreateMap<LocationEntity, Location>()
            .ConstructUsing((source, _) => new Location(source.Name, new GeoLocation(source.Latitude, source.Longitude)));
    });
```

However, this still complains about the `LocationEntity` -> `Location` mapping:

```
AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
===============================================
LocationEntity -> Location (Destination member list)
UserQuery+LocationEntity -> UserQuery+Location (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
GeoLocation
```

Unsure what else to do, I added a `ForMember` call to the `LocationEntity` -> `Location` mapping:

```
config
    .CreateMap<LocationEntity, Location>()
    .ConstructUsing((source, _) => new Location(source.Name, new GeoLocation(source.Latitude, source.Longitude)))
    .ForMember(
        x => x.GeoLocation,
        options => options.MapFrom((source, target, _, context) => new GeoLocation(source.Latitude, source.Longitude)));
```

Whilst this solves the problem, it seems to me that my mappings are already becoming somewhat complex. I'm wondering: is there a better way to go about this that doesn't sacrifice the design of my object models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object model design basically allows mapping (converting) only via construction, hence can't benefit the most of the AutoMapper automatic and explicit mapping capabilities.

`ConstructUsing` is used to select a non default constructor for creating destination instances, but still requires member mapping.

What you need is the `ConvertUsing` method:

> Skip member mapping and use a custom expression to convert to the destination type

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Location, LocationEntity>()
        .ConvertUsing(source => new LocationEntity(source.Name, source.GeoLocation?.Latitude ?? 0.0, source.GeoLocation?.Longitude ?? 0));
    config.CreateMap<LocationEntity, Location>()
        .ConvertUsing(source => new Location(source.Name, new GeoLocation(source.Latitude, source.Longitude)));
});
```

Comment: AM can [map with constructors](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

`ConvertUsing` is helpful if you *really* want to take over the mapping. But more idiomatic in this case would be to map through [constructors](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html). By adding another constructor to Location (private if needed) you could even remove `ForCtorParam`.

```
CreateMap<Location, LocationEntity>().ReverseMap().ForCtorParam("geoLocation", o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s));

class LocationEntity
{
public LocationEntity(string name, double geoLocationLatitude, double geoLocationLongitude)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Latitude = geoLocationLatitude;
    this.Longitude = geoLocationLongitude;
}
public string Name { get; }
public double Latitude { get; }
public double Longitude { get; }
}
```