# Automapper ConstructUsing not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I am using automapper in my asp.net core project and it's my first time with that library. The data flow is as follows: Model->DomainModel->ViewModel. Automapper is used for mapping between those. I have problems using ConstructUsing. It seems to me it is not working. 
Part of the data profile class:

```
 CreateMap<ClinicD, ClinicViewModel>()
            .ConstructUsing(x => new ClinicViewModel
            {
                Active = x.Active,
                CooperationStart = x.CooperationStart,
                CooperationEnd = x.CooperationEnd,
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                AddressId = x.Address.Id,
                FlatNo = x.Address.FlatNo,
                City = x.Address.City,
                HouseNumber = x.Address.HouseNumber,
                Street = x.Address.Street,
                Postcode = x.Address.Postcode
            })
            .ForMember(x => x.ChosenSpecialities, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Specialities, opt => opt.Ignore());
public class ClinicViewModel : CooperationSpotViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<int> _chosenSpecialities;


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Specialities
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> ChosenSpecialities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_chosenSpecialities == null)
                _chosenSpecialities = new List<int>();
            return _chosenSpecialities;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                _chosenSpecialities = value;
        }
    }
} 
public abstract class CooperationSpotViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CooperationStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CooperationEnd { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }


    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlatNo { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
public class ClinicD : CooperationSpotD
{
    public IEnumerable<SpecialityD> Specialities
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
public abstract class CooperationSpotD 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CooperationStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CooperationEnd { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public AddressD Address { get; set; }
}
```

A similar issue occurs for me in several spots, so I am guessing, I must be doing something basic wrong. The exception that occurs:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>   For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ClinicD -> ClinicViewModel (Destination member list)
>   SeeingEyeDog.BusinessLogic.Models.ClinicD -> SeeingEyeDog.Models.ClinicViewModel (Destination member list)
>   Unmapped properties:
>   Street
>   HouseNumber
>   FlatNo
>   City
>   Postcode

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu this says nothing about ConstructUsing.

Comment: What you're doing here is manual mapping, you don't need AM for that. That links explains how you can achieve the same _actually_ using AM for mapping.

Comment: check this link, basically try `ConvertUsing()` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661190/automapper-requiring-mapping-members-and-constructor